# Formula INDIRETO dando erro em Português, mas em Inglês funciona

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma planilha que funciona normalmente quando aberta em um Excel em inglês, porém quando muda a linguagem para Português ocorre um erro na fórmula.

Eu consegui reduzir o problema à formula abaixo, mas não consegui decifrar o que ela significa ou como funciona.

```
=INDIRETO('2021'!R6C36:R29C36;FALSO)
```

`2021` = Nome da planilha
`R6C36:R29C36` = Essa parte não entendi
`R6:R29` = Seria o range desejado para a consulta

A fórmula para o Excel em inglês é a seguinte:

```
=INDIRECT('2021'!R6C36:R29C36;FALSE)
```

Tentei alterar o separador de `;` para `,` como sugerido e apresenta esse erro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o separador de parâmetros na fórumuals é diferente entre PT e EN, num é `;`  no outro é `,`

Comment: Adicionei duas imagens, com o Excel em inglês a fórmula esta funcionando com o separador `;`

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/indireto-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-indireto-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261

Comment: Então Gabriel, releia o primeiro comentário que provavelmente resolverá o problema.

Comment: Bom dia Woss, quando eu tento alterar o `;` por `,` o excel não aceita, mensagem de erro "Encontramos um problema nesta fórmula."

Comment: `;` é para o Excel em português mesmo, e `,` para o inglês. Quanto a citação à documentação, infelizmente ela é uma mistura de inglês e português... Há partes que chama o comando de `INDIRETO`, outras de `INDIRECT`, e não há menção à "tradução" da referência (`R` e `C`) conforme foi respondido pelo AP abaixo. Não acho que a pergunta deva ser fechada.

Answer (score 1):

Problema resolvido, o que acontece é que utilizando `FALSO` na fórmula `=INDIRETO...` o excel utiliza a referência L1C1 que até então eu não conhecia, ele referência um endereço na planilha por LINHA e COLUNA ou seja `R6C36:R29C36` R = Row , C = Column em inglês, mas em português a referência muda, L = Linha e C = Coluna.

Exemplo:.

Excel em inglês : `=INDIRECT(R6C36:R29C36;FALSE)`

Excel em português : `=INDIRETO(L6C36:L29C36;FALSO)`